# where the TCP/IP protocol suite ll be located ? if we have to add some functionality to it then where to implement?

Tags: tcp, protocols, network-protocols

I just wanted to know where the TCP/IP protocol suite will be located...is tat in NIC? 
if we have to add some functionality to it then where to implement?

Comment: Unanswerable without context. What is your setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP/IP stack is implemented by your operating system. NIC's aren't involved.

Comment: if we have to add some functionality to it then where to implement?

Comment: ***What*** functionality? To do what? With what end goal in mind? Your question is on par with "I need something" - it's so vague that it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @Neel: what OS are you talking about?

Comment: actually i wanted to know if v wanna add some functionality or just to change something in a particular layer of OSI model; then where to do those implementations?
say in physical layer if i want some changes where all i can make. Can we do such changes?

Comment: @Neel:First of all.. what kind of changes are you talking about? That's improbable: changing TCP protocol would require that every other TCP machine you are talking with should implement your changes too.